# How do I identify the i,j position of a specific value on a Matlab matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinates

For example, I have a matrix A with 400 lines and 4000 columns which is mostly composed by zeros but have three ones. I do need to know exactly what position these ones occupy, let's say A(30,4000), A(400,3050) and A(50,200).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do:

```
[row,col] = find(A);
```

This will give you the row and column locations of all non-zero entries.  `row` would contain all of the row locations and `col` would contain all of the column locations as `N x 1` vectors, where `N` is the number of non-zero elements.  In your example, the above output would be equivalent to:

```
row = [30; 400; 50];
col = [4000; 3050; 200];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is pretty simple and worked just like I wanted!

Comment: @RayzaRosaTavaresRodrigues - No problem at all.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `find(.)` function.
For example if you have:

```
q=[1 2 3;1 2 4];
[r c]=find(q==2)
```

in this case `r` includes rows and `c` includes columns of desired value.